# Is there any good user interface add-on for WinDbg for not to use command line debugging?

Tags: user-interface, windbg

I have to use WinDbg but I do not like gebug.exe command-line style. Is there any plugin or anything else which makes it look and feel like 21st century debugger?

Comment: Consider the new WinDbg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46085954/1724702

Answer (score 2):

For managed code there's [SOS Assist](http://www.thinktecture.com/SOSAssist). There's also a PowerShell integration module called [PowerDbg](http://www.codeplex.com/powerdbg). However, I actually prefer WinDbg over these, so I'm not the right person to ask.

Comment: I agree, sosAssist looks a million times friendlier, but you quickly get to the point where it is hiding info from you or you can't get what you need

Comment: SOS assist link doesn't work anymore, find it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120710004518/http://www.thinktecture.com/SOSAssist)

Comment: Also, consider the new WinDbg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46085954/1724702